# GPS readings getting swapped

Tags: ros, gpsd-client

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Two of my GPS readings get swapped as follows:

I have a robot (named raven) which runs a gps and uses the gpsd_client and utm_odometry to publish on a topic named raven_gps_odom. Similarly I have a laptop(named uav) which runs another gps and publishes on laptop_gps_odom. The laptop's ROS_MASTER is set to raven and the two run on the same network. The config files are  [here](http://pastebin.com/kXC2qHJT) .

When I do a  `rostopic echo laptop_gps_odom`  and  `rostopic echo /raven_gps_odom`  several times consecutively I find that their gps readings get swapped every 10 seconds or so.

Why is this so?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11524/gps-readings-getting-swapped/) by [PKG](https://answers.ros.org/users/671/pkg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 365 on 2011-10-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It doesn't look like you are remapping the output topics from the `gpsd_client`. Since they are using the same rosmaster, you are publishing from two different drivers on the same topic.

You should remap both of the outputs for each `gpsd_client` and the appropriate inputs to `utm_odometry`. Another option would be to run both sets in their own namespaces.

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2011-10-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2